# Permutation tests for large sequences

Tags: algorithms, statistics, random

I would like to perform a [permutation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests) on a particularly large data set, i.e. around 4 million entries. Basically, I need to get some number of random permutations of this data set. Usual way to do this, is a Fisher-Yates shuffle, but it's pretty much [limited by period of a PRNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062741/maximal-length-of-list-to-shuffle-with-python-random-shuffle). That is, to a sequence no longer than around 2080.

Is there a solution to randomly permuting much larger sequences?

EDIT:
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92287/a-proof-of-correctness-of-durstenfelds-random-permutation-algorithm) is an interesting related discussion on random shuffle algorithms and how much are they limited by RNG.

Comment: (Note that while I saw the comment discouraging you from posting on StackOverflow, IMO it's perfectly on-topic there as well under the algorithm tag)

Comment: @amit Thanks. I found a guideline post stating something like 'If you're not in front of your IDE, use Programmers'. So, well, right now I'm not:)

Comment: Perhaps you can get more insights asking on GNU GSL mailing list.

Comment: If one is simply concerned with preventing the erroneous occurrence of repetitions, perhaps one could use a combination of (1) randomness tests and (2) a true hardware random source, which is used to periodically reseed a PRNG. These techniques are used in encryption. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @rwong Thanks. I was thinking about block ciphers, which are said to be built upon 'pseudorandom permutations', but I know very little about cryptography and not sure whether it suits the task. Actually, my question could be reformulated as 'does random shuffle uniformly sample from all possible permutations?' If not, I could be introducing even more error, when using permutation tests.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "some number of random permutations"? There might be different techniques if you need 100 permutations vs 1e10 permutations.

Answer (score 1):

I think that something is unclear in the question.  Are you asking:

1) Can I generate a large number of random permutations of 4000000 elements using a PRNG, where a large number is something like 100000000000 random permutations?

Or

2) Can I generate EVERY random permutation of 4000000 elements using a PRNG?

The answer to the first question is yes, and to the second question is no.  Take Mersenne Twister as an example.  To generate one random permutation, you need to generate 8.1e+7 random bits, or around 2^21 random 32-bit numbers.  Since the period of Mersenne Twister is 2^19997, you can continue and generate a whopping 2^19976 random permutations, many more than you will ever need.

However, if you wanted generate EVERY possible random permutation, you would need to generate at least 2^8100000 random permutations, which is more than 2^19976.  But there isn't any practical reason for generating every possible permutation.

Regarding the other question in the comments about whether a random shuffle would sample uniformly from all possible permutations: the answer is yes.  As long as your RNG can generate 80000000 consecutive uniformly random bits, which Mersenne Twister can, then your sampling will be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the minimal number of bits you need to use in order to get a truly (pseudo) uniform random permutation.

Let the number of bits generated be `b`. We want to find `b` such that `2^b = n!`, so you are going to need `log_2(n!)` bits at least in order to generate a uniformly distributed permutation which is ~= 8.1*10^7

Fisher-yates shuffle (assuming 32bits integers) will need to generate 32*n~=32*4,000,000~=1.28*10^8 random bits

While indeed there is some waste, it is not as significant as one might think (*1.5 more bits are needed), and to get a uniformly distributed permutation, you are going to need much more than 2080 random integers generated either way.

Comment: So the bottom line is, it's impossible with existing PRNGs, and to achieve this number of permutations, we need a PRNG with internal state of at least ~8.1e7?

Comment: Not a PRNG expert, so I have no idea what the internal state should be, but you need at least 8.1e7 pseudo random bits to achieve uniform distribution.

Comment: There is lots of literature about long period RNGs. For example, here is 2^4096: http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3115. Cryptographers love this stuff.

Comment: @david.pfx Mersenne twister has a period of 2^19997-1, yet still much smaller than 2^(8.1e7)... If I have a correct understanding of a generators period.

Comment: @Oreochromis No, you need 8.1e7 bits, not 2^8.1e7. (You need log_2(4,000,000!) ~= 8.1e7)

Comment: @amit I think, if a period of a generator is a length of its non-repeating output sequence (say, `n`), then a bijection exists between this sequence and a subset {1...n} of natural numbers. Thus, I suppose, a length of sequence determines a range, within which a PRNG can generate uniformly distributed values.